# Who should own the root folder of a drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, ntfs, ownership

All partitions are NTFS. The system is Windows 7 Pro. It does not belong to a domain. I do use shared folders occasionally (both via the Homegroup and old school sharing). Should I set the owner to be *Administrators* or *SYSTEM* for a

A) **fixed drive partitions?** (C: and D:)

B) **removable drive partitions?** (U: and V:)

C) Is it ok to **make every object on the drive inherit** the new ownership?

I just realized that I had some messy settings because I turned UAC on for the first time in years and I am now getting some undesirable prompts. I already have permissions set properly and I am only concerned with ownership.

Answer (score 0):

As long as permissions are set in such a way that works well for you, it's best to leave ownership alone. By default, the drive Windows is installed on (typically `C:`) will be owned by TrustedInstaller, as will many of the system folders and files below it. You can't even change the ownership without going through a lot of steps.

If you're adding an external drive, just format it and let Windows worry about setting the ownership. You can configure ownership yourself for subfolders as needed.

Comment: I''m not touching C: because I am not having any problems but the other partitions need to be fixed.